# Comparing memory usage of shell script and Python script for same task

Tags: python, shell, memory, valgrind, performance-testing

Assume two scripts: (a) a *bash* shell script that calls a JAVA jar (hereafter `my_shell_script`), and (b) a Python script that imports functions from other Python packages but that does not call any non-Python package or software (hereafter `my_Python_script`). Both scripts have the same purpose: They take the same input (hereafter `testinput`) and generate roughly the same output.

I would like to measure and compare the memory usage of both scripts as a function of time as they execute.

To that end, I execute each script via `valgrind` using `massif` (setting the time_unit to milliseconds), followed by a summary of the massif output via `ms_print`.

```
INF=testinput

# Testing Shell script
valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes --time-unit=ms --massif-out-file=${INF}_shell.out bash my_shell_script -f $INF -j my_java_jar
ms_print --threshold=50.0 ${INF}_shell.out > ${INF}_shell.summary

# Testing Python script
valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes --time-unit=ms --massif-out-file=${INF}_Python.out python2 my_python_script $INF
ms_print --threshold=50.0 ${INF}_Python.out > ${INF}_Python.summary
```

While valgrind/massif record a memory usage for `my_python_script` that is roughly consistent with what I see via `htop`, this is not the case for `my_shell_script`. The statistics on `htop` indicate a GB of memory usage during the execution of `my_shell_script`, yet valgrind/massif record only a few dozen MB of memory used.

Thus, I suspect that valgrind/massif record the memory usage of the execution of the bash code, but not of the JAVA jar that the bash code is calling.

How can I measure the memory usage of `my_shell_script` as a function of time correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option --trace-children=yes|no indicates to trace (or not) the children. The default value is no, which means that the shell executing the script will
be under valgrind, but not the launched python or java process.

So, specify --trace-children=yes.

Be sure to use e.g. a %p in the massif out file argument, otherwise all the
processes (e.g. the shell and its children) will write to the same file, which will not work properly.